# Generate all trees of height n with only 3 values and 2 operators

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, binary-tree, combinations, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this type of tree:

```
type op = Add | Mult ;;

type tree =
  | Value of int
  | Node of tree * op * tree
;;
```

It is a syntaxic binary tree. It means each nodes is an operator and each leaves represent a number. Here I need to work modulo 3 so my values are `[0;1;2]`.

For instance the expression `let e1 = Node(Node(Value 1,Add,Value 2),Add,Value 2) in` represents the folling expression : `((1+2)+2)`.

Now I need to create a function `generate_height : int n -> tree list` which returns all possible trees of height n.

A little drawing can help :
[image: for n = 1]
[image: n=2]

My initial idea was to generate all empty trees (we don't care about values in leaves we just se them to 0 but we need all combination of nodes)

```
let generate_empty n =

  let rec gen_rec n op =
    match n with 
    | 0 -> Value 0
    | _ -> Node(gen_rec (n-1) op,op, gen_rec (n-1) op)
  in

 
  (gen_rec n Add)::[gen_rec n Mult]

;;
```

But it just return two trees : one with only an add op and the other one with mult. I don't know how to make all combinations of operators.

And secondly if this function was successful I wanted to iterate through all "empty trees" and change leaves with all combinations of `[0;1;2]`.

I have a beginning of something

```
let modify_trees_empty list =

  let rec modify_leaf empty_tree = 

    match empty_tree with 
    | Value x -> Value x
    | Node(Value x, op, Value y) -> Node(Val 1, op, Val 1);(*here I want Node(0,op,0),(0,1)..(2,2)*)
    | Node (g, op, d) -> Node(modify_leaf g, op, modify_leaf d)  
  
  in

  let rec iterate_list_and_apply list =
    match list with 
    | [] -> []
    | el :: tl -> [modify_leaf el] @ iterate_list_and_apply tl
  in

  iterate_list_and_apply list
;;
```

But It just changes leaves to one and that's not what I wanted ^^

Comment: A "simple" recursion suffices, since it's clear that the maximum depth argument is just decremented for each recursion. But the function cannot return just one tree; it must return a (possibly lazy) list of all possibilities, and these must be combined using a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem :

you want all trees of size `n`

## Solution :

- if `n = 0` then it's the list of all the `Value i` (in your case, `i` is `0`, `1` or `2`)
- if `n > 0` then :

  - list all the trees of length `n-1` in a list named `sub_trees` for example.
  - Then make a function `cartesian_product` that, given a list, returns all the possible couple of list's elements. For example, `cartesian_product [1,2,3]` returns `[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)]`
  - Then for each possible operator (here `Mult` and `Add`), returns all the trees made with this operator and a couple from `cartesian_product sub_trees`

## Remarks concerning your current code

Here are some remarks about your code that could help you to discover new things.

For

```ml
let rec iterate_list_and_apply list =
    match list with 
    | [] -> []
    | el :: tl -> [modify_leaf el] @ iterate_list_and_apply tl
  in
```

You should not use the `@` operator to add an only element to a list, instead use the `::` operator

```ml
| el :: tl -> modify_leaf el :: iterate_list_and_apply tl
```

Also note that you can also use `List.iter modify_leaf list` which does the same as `iterate_list_and_apply list`,  if you want to make your program shorter (but coding those simple function is a good exercise too)

Also, here is a syntactic sugar you may not know : 
Instead of

```ml
let rec modify_leaf empty_tree = 
   match empty_tree with 
    | ... -> ...
    | ... -> ...
```

you can do

```ml
let rec modify_leaf = function
    | ... -> ...
    | ... -> ...
```

Comment: okay thanks for you detailed hint, I'll try it ;)

Comment: @ThéoExagon, you should accept the answer unless you expect someone to give you the exact solution which will likely not happen